# How to format a date field into diferente languages in the same command? (multiple locales)

Tags: mysql, date-format

The following will return the day in Italian:

```
SET lc_time_names = 'it_IT';
select date_format('2018/01/01','%W') as day_italian;
```

However I need to convert or format the date into multiple languages, so it would return me another column in English, Japanese, so on...

My problem is that I have to set the locale BEFORE running the select command.

Comment: The only way to solve this task I see is to create a table which keep matches between term in std (en-US, for example) locale, another locale and this term in another locale. Joining this table to a query source and replacing terms in a date formatted in std locale to a locale you specify will give desired result. I.e. create your own locale-convertion (maybe in a function form).

Comment: sounds reasonable @Akina

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a Stored Function, you can get it all in a single `SELECT`.

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE FUNCTION WDay(_d DATE, _locale VARCHAR(5))
    RETURNS VARCHAR(22)
    DETERMINISTIC
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
BEGIN
    SET @@lc_time_names = _locale;
    RETURN DATE_FORMAT(_d, '%W');
END;
//
DELIMITER ;

SELECT WDay(NOW(), 'it_IT') AS it,
       WDay(NOW(), 'es_ES') AS es,
       WDay(NOW(), 'en_US') AS us;

+----------+--------+----------+
| it       | es     | us       |
+----------+--------+----------+
| giovedì  | jueves | Thursday |
+----------+--------+----------+
```

Caveat:  This has the side effect of changing `@@lc_time_names`.

Comment: I love it! Maybe in the last line I can set the lc_time_names to my own "default language"

Comment: @Calvin - sounds like a plan.

Answer (score 2):

You could simply pass the third parameter as a local value. ^^

> SELECT DATE_FORMAT("2023-06-15", '%W %d %M %Y','it_IT') as date;

output: giovedì 15 giugno 2023

> SELECT DATE_FORMAT("2023-06-15", '%W %d %M %Y','fr_FR') as date;

output  : jeudi 15 juin 2023

> SELECT DATE_FORMAT("2023-06-15", '%W %d %M %Y','ja_JP') as date;

output : 木曜日 15 6月 2023

for more information, here  [MySQL Server Locale Support](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/locale-support.html)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I've looked into the source code around lc_time_names and there is no solution around getting multiple lc_time_name translations with a single query.

MariaDB has an [information_schema table called locales](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/information-schema-locales-table/) however it doesn't got as far as exporting the `lc_time_names` of days/months etc. All the names are stored in the server (code, not a database), and it would be moderately easy to export these to an information_schema table, however noone has written the code to do this.